# In which case `gethostname()` returns false?

Tags: php

Talking about https://www.php.net/gethostname

I'm writing a function that relies on the hostname.

In what scenario this method returns `false`?

Comment: It is mentioned in the document itself

Comment: @User863 it's not

Comment: @User863 there is no information about failure scenarios on the page. If you see information, show me.

Comment: Looking at the [correct line for the function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/e836143ad7b4205ef294dd3094ecd6a1fec9ac9e/ext/standard/dns.c#L133), it returns false if it can't fetch the host for whatever reason. `php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Unable to fetch host [%d]: %s", errno, strerror(errno));`

Comment: Someone has information about "whatever reason"?

Comment: Whoops. You are right

Comment: If you really think this question is not clear, let me know what information you need to make it clear

Comment: @DanielW. See 'errors' section of docs of the corresponding syscall: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an interesting question. Because under linux, I query the hostname in the console. And it's always there. So when does an error occur? When I switch off my computer?!

The link https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html from @CherryDT
helps.  And for me the most unlikely error would be if the hostname is too long. But how long is long?

```
ERRORS
       EFAULT name is an invalid address.

       EINVAL len is negative or, for sethostname(), len is larger than
              the maximum allowed size.

       ENAMETOOLONG
              (glibc gethostname()) len is smaller than the actual size.
              (Before version 2.1, glibc uses EINVAL for this case.)

       EPERM  For sethostname(), the caller did not have the
              CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability in the user namespace associated
              with its UTS namespace (see namespaces(7)).
```

Comment: "I query the hostname in the console. And it's always there." Tell that to the facebook engineers who nuked their dns routing :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Facebook_outage

Comment: So it seems in PHP the function returns false only when the system is heavily corrupted or the RAM is damaged... okay lol. In that case, other functions would lead to a segmentation fault, wouldn't they?